# UICollectionView inside UITableViewCell slow srolling

Tags: swift, uitableview, scroll, uicollectionview

I know that this question was asked a couple of times, but other solutions didn't work for me.

I have this model:

```
var notifications = [Notification]()

Notification:
let user: User (name, profileimage, etc)
let items: [Movies] (movie has image, name, etc)
```

So i display my notifications inside a tableview, each cell has profile info at the top and collectionview with items bellow.

Inside my tableviewcell, i have to reloadData of my collectionview to display correct movies. I know that probably reloadData method causes this lagging, but are there any solutions to avoid it?

TableViewcell:

```
var notification: Notification! {
   didSet {
      collectionView.reloadData();
   }
}
```

I also tried this thing inside tablecell and call this method in willDisplayTableViewcell, but it doesn't help at all:

```
func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(forRow row: Int) {
    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Images are loading using kingfisher, so it's fine in other places in my project.

```
            userProfileImage.kf.setImage(
                with: URL(string: profileImage),
                options: [
                    .processor(DownsamplingImageProcessor(size: CGSize(width: 175, height: 175))),
                    .scaleFactor(UIScreen.main.scale),
                    .transition(.fade(0.2)),
                ]
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would comment out the code you have shown above as it will only get in the way and give false readings. My gut feeling is somehow you have managed to directly wire your notifications to your tableview / collection view and they are running on a background thread. What I would do to test this theory is wrap code anywhere where the UI is going to be updated with a perform on main thread like this

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { [unowned self] in
    //Your UI update code within cellforRow / cellForItem (both table and collection view) Here
}
```

Try doing this one by one until you find the culprit and for a better solution try to refactor so you don't have to force this Main thread directive.

Comment: To be honest, i don't understand your question. I have a tableview where each cell has horizontal collectionview. Collectionview cell has image inside it. So when i scroll down my tableview, i have to reload my collectionview inside cell so it causes lagging

Comment: OK really simple explanation. I think your collection view images are trying to load into the imageview from a background thread as opposed to the main thread. Google threads if this doesn't make sense. What you have written above in func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate makes absolutely no sense whatsoever so I would at least comment it out so it doesn't get in the way. If you want a quick way to test if it is indeed a background thread problem, the place where you are setting the inageview.image can be wrapped in the code I provided which will force it to work on the main thread.

Comment: The main problem was in Kingfisher framework. When i switch to Nuke, performance grow up.